# How to subscribe to Database attach/detach events?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-smo

I am writing a C# application which works with databases and creates a new database on monthly basis.

The older databases can be detached and attached by a user through SQL Management studio or other ways.

I am trying to figure out how to listen to sql server events (IF they exist) and catch when database has been attached or detached.

When `attach` operation occurs my application has to check the database and update table schema to the latest version.

I am also learning the SQL SMO and was thinking this library would present me the event listeners, but i fail to find them.

I could, of course, run a thread or a timer which would check for new databases every couple seconds. I have tried that and running `SQLServer.Databases.Refresh()` updates the database list which i can then iterate and work with.

But is there a simpler way of achieving this? Maybe there is an event like `OnDatabaseAttach` somewhere?

**EDIT**

Thank you **elsausmc** for directing me into the right direction.
I have done a little search on `ServerEventSet` and came across [this page](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/8683936/).

I did a quick test and it turns out, that `ServerEvent.CreateDatabase` does fire up when database has been created OR attached, however `ServerEvent.DropDatabase` does not fire on detach. Might be some other event perhaps. Thats for me to find out next. Thank you :)

Been googling with 10+ different phrases and never came up with something simple as `smo server events`. Silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there isn't Attach/Detach in SMO and it is covered under CREATE and DROP? ServerEventSet.CreateDatabase and ServerEventSet.DropDatabase and handle the event? Sorry if you already looked into this.